# 30 Ohm Thermistor blown

Tags: power, current

This is a follow on question from a previous one about a blown fluorescent UV ballast.

I have discovered that the in-rush current thermistor is blown.  Question 1 is whether it is worth changing it, or is the rest of the circuit likely to be damaged?  Question 2 is about how close the spec of the original and the replacement have to match.  The original is an SG38 and after searching for a while I found the first spec below.  The closest match I can find on the internet is the SL22 30005, which is the 5th line of the table.  Do you think these are interchangeable?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That inrush thermistor is there for a reason, and if it's blown you'd better have a very good idea of why. Otherwise, it may just blow again if you install a replacement. It's not quite as bad an idea as putting a penny in a fuseholder because the fuse keeps blowing, but it's not good.

Comment: As far as my couple of hours of research suggests, the termistor limits the current drawn by a couple of large capacitors when the circuit is energized.  Of course, this my be an erroneous view of the way the circuit operates.  When a control board stops working it is highly likely that a single component has failed.  My question can therefore be refined to the following:  if the thermistor is the primary fault and it developed a dead short, is it likely to have damaged other components?  I think it is worth trying so I still need to know if the spec of the replacement is close enough to work.